# Why does Mathematica stop when run in the background in command line mode?

Tags: kernel, mac-os-x, linux, scripting

If I try to start a Mathematica script in the background from the command line, like this:

```
math -script someFile.m &
```

then the process gets automatically suspended.  Here's a terminal transcript for clarifications:

[image]

This happens both on Linux and OS X.  Other programs don't typically stop when run in the background.

- Why does this happen?
- What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: should this be tagged as `bug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mathematica* for unknown reasons is waiting for input. Possible solution

```bash
echo | math -script someFile.m &
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your shell doesn't allow background processes to print to the console. For instance tcsh has this behavior by default:

```
% echo "a"&
[1] 26502
% 
[1]  + Suspended (tty output)        echo a
% fg
echo a
a
```

In pretty much all shells you should be able to disable this behavior with `stty -tostop`

```
% stty -tostop
% echo "a" &
[1] 26539
a
%
[1]    Done                          echo a
```

Re-enable the behavior with `stty tostop`

You could also redirect the output so it never hits stdout at all:

```
% echo "a" > /dev/null &
```

Comment: My test `.m` file simply contained a `Print`.  I tested this on Mac with bash and on Linux with tcsh (and later bash).  In both cases, the math process gets suspended and doesn't print anything until I resume it with `fg`.  However, all other processes (including `echo` and python scripts) are able to print stuff to the terminal while in the background.

Comment: @Szabolcs Strange, I'm stumped