# When running Mathematica from a Linux terminal, how can I prevent a script from terminating upon logout?

Tags: kernel, linux

I am running Mathematica on a remote Linux cluster, by the terminal, using the `math` command.  (I do not have access to a terminal GUI.  For example, when I type the command `mathematica`, I get this error message: `Can't open display ""`.)

I write Mathematica code in a text file (e.g., `test.txt`) and pass it to `math` using either the command

```
math < test.txt
```

or the command

```
math -script test.txt
```

Both of these methods work fine for starting a Mathematica job.  However, when I log out of the terminal -- or even when a brief loss of internet connection interrupts my connection to the remote cluster -- the Mathematica script is terminated.  When I log back in the terminal, no Mathematica processes (i.e., `MathKernel`) are running.

To prevent this termination upon logout, I have tried using the standard Linux program [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), which is a command telling the terminal to ignore the `HUP` (hangup) signal; output is redirected to a file `nohup.out`.  I use `nohup` with any of the following commands:

```
nohup math < test.txt
```

or

```
nohup math < test.txt &
```

or

```
nohup math -script test.txt
```

or

```
nohup math -script test.txt &
```

These commands **all** *start* the Mathematica job fine, but when I logout and log back in to the terminal, no `MathKernel` or similar processes are running (as verified by `ps` and by `ps -u myusername`).  The situation is the same regardless of whether my job is a single kernel job or a parallel, multikernel job.  Since the jobs *start* fine -- including those ending with the `&` symbol to force the job to the background -- I do not think that I am having the same "background job suspension" problem as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34315/why-does-mathematica-stop-when-run-in-the-background-in-command-line-mode).

Do you have any thoughts on how I can prevent the terminal from terminating jobs when I logout or my connection is briefly interrupted?  The `nohup` method above works for me with other programs, but for some reason not with Mathematica.

(A toy test example is `Table[Length[FactorInteger[10^50 + n]], {n, 50}]`, which takes about 30 seconds on the terminal.)

Comment: Have you considered using a [terminal multiplexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) like GNU Screen or tmux? Then you can [keep your entire console session running after you logout](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option would be to use the [`at`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm) command to create detached jobs:

```
echo "math -script test.txt" | at now
```

Comment: Very useful and short!

Answer (score 19):

You need to *daemonize* your script:

```
nohup math -script test.txt 0<&- &>/dev/null &
```

Now this will run as a background process with no output captured. If your script does indeed produce output, just replace /dev/null with the filename.

In order to daemonize something you need to disconnect all the 
automatically connected streams (stdin, stdout, stderr).

I don't know really if this is a Mathematica question, since it is more
unix/linux related, but I got tired of only giving comments. ;)

Another trick is just to double background your script, which will 
make nohup of no need:

```
(math -script test.txt &)& (* very /bin/bash related *)
```

Comment: I hope the poor script won't feel too hurt by such [slander](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/demonize) :-)

Comment: :) but since the daemon (where it all relates from) looks rather friendly http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/55/Bsd_daemon.jpg I would not fear too much on that script.

Comment: @Stefan @Szabolcs Thanks so much to both of you.  I know that I am getting more into a Linux question, but I don't completely understand why just `nohup math -script &` does not work.  For some other programs that I use, this works and dumps all the output to a file called `nohup.out`.  I *would* like to capture the output, so I will go with your first suggestion.  If I want to capture to a file `nohup.out`, do I just do `nohup math -script test.txt 0<&- &>./nohup.out &`?

Comment: @Andrew yup indeed. worked for me for several years.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks.  So apparently those extra options make the difference.  I am just confused why `nohup math -script test.txt &` does not work.

Comment: @Andrew nohup is just catching the SIGHUP signal, but does not disconnect the standard file descriptors. depends on the software how much they rely on those. but to disconnect a session from a software which does hold a connection on them you must detach with all the file descriptors available. therefore you need that "ugly" trick.

Comment: @Szabolcs @Stefan Hmm.  Unfortunately, `nohup math -script test.txt 0<&- &>./myout.log &` did not work.  When `test.txt` has the content: `Print[DateString[]];
time = Table[Length[FactorInteger[10^50 + n]], {n, 50}] // AbsoluteTiming;
Print[time];
Print[DateString[]];`, the resulting `myout.log` contains only the output `"Mon 24 Feb 2014 17:50:03"`, suggesting that the process was terminated upon logout.

Comment: hmm..that's weird, since this does work on my machine (debian). if your server is ubuntu, please use instead the *start-stop-daemon"

Comment: I'd rather do `math -script test.txt & disown`, where `&` puts the script into background, and `disown` detaches it from the current terminal - instead of all that manual magic with redirections and `nohup`, which would also create a `nohup.out` file.

Answer (score 15):

You can use GNU `screen` to make a sort of persistent terminal that allows you to resume work wherever you left off.  Take a look at the many [tutorials](http://www.phacks.net/how-to-use-gnu-screen/) available.

It's not completely clear from your question whether the better solution is this, or `nohup` (see Stefan's answer).

Use `nohup` if your workflow is non-interactive: log in, start a batch job that writes results to a file, log out, log back in the next day to retrieve results.

Use `screen` for an interactive workflow: log in, start `math` in interactive mode, disconnect because your internet connections is interrupted (or you need to go for lunch), return later to continue the interactive session.

Short tutorial on screen:

1. Log in, and start `screen`.
2. Start `math`, do interactive work.
3. When you need to log out, first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to detach from screen (you do not need to put `math` to the background).  Then log out using `exit`.  Do not log out using `exit` before detaching from `screen`, otherwise this will close `screen` for good.
4. Log back in and start `screen` as `screen -r`.  This returns you to where you left off.

I have in fact used this for running long jobs with Mathematica.  The reason why I preferred to run `math` interactively instead of using it in batch mode to run scripts was that I could interrupt the evaluation temporarily using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> to enter an interactive [`Dialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dialog.html) and examine the state of the calculation.  (Note that that is a potentially dangerous thing to do, and how to do it safely would be the topic of a different Q/A... Just warning you.)

Comment: Well, this is a really nice approach on an interactive workflow...especially the Dialog part, though dangerous, but it is indeed a nice option. Very elaborated indeed.

Comment: @Stefan If I remember correctly, interrupting parallel calculations was not safe.  I don't think I ran into problems otherwise, but be sure to test interruptibility on a short job before interrupting a job that would run for a week ...

Comment: I always preferred screen to nohup as I could use multiple "windows" (screens?) to monitor progress, plus logging. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a shell dependent issue.  With csh/tsch the `&` automatically `nohup`'s, so just this works:

```
 math -script test.m < /dev/null &
```

There seems to be a mathematica/csh issue that the script hangs if disconnected form stdin even though it doesn't try to read anything

Comment: Thanks.  I am using `bash`, so I don't think the above works for me, but I am sure it works for `csh`/`tsch`.