# How to keep remote Mathematica GUI running when the connection is lost

Tags: remote-access, networking, interruption

I am running Mathematica on a remote Linux cluster using X11/SSH.
I'm using the GUI and not the kernels in remote because this is the only way they let me use it.
I have a long notebook that I open and evaluate.
Sometimes however the connection is lost, the GUI shuts down and I have to restart the evaluation anew.
I searched and found: [When running Mathematica from a Linux terminal, how can I prevent a script from terminating upon logout?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42838/when-running-mathematica-from-a-linux-terminal-how-can-i-prevent-a-script-from/42841#42841), however these methods don't work for a GUI.
Is there a way to keep the GUI afloat if the connection is lost for a little bit?

Comment: Maybe useful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: How did you managed to set it up? Is there an instruction somewhere?

Comment: I did not set it up. I just asked permission to use the machine. I'm trying to use tmux but there was no connection lost for now so I still don't know if it works